# Initialise an array and compute the frequency of numbers in a range

Tags: java, arrays, range, frequency

// note this is a practice question
I'm trying to Initialise an array with 50 integer values and compute the frequency of numbers in the range 10 .. 19.(with a user input)
So far i have the user input working only allowing numbers between 10 and 19 to be entered, But my next step and problem is to calculate the frequency of what numbers the user used in the input. Any help in starting this next step would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ex1partA {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kbin = new Scanner(System.in);

        int list[]=new int[50];
        int i=0;

        System.out.print("\n\tInput numbers from 10 to 19: \n");

        while (i < 50) {
            int value = kbin.nextInt();

            if (value >= 10 & value <= 19) {
                list[i] = value;
                i++;
            } else {
                System.out.println("!! Bad number !!");
            }

        }

        for (int value : list) {
            System.out.println(" "+value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean you want to count how many of the 50 numbers are in a certain range?

Comment: build a map from user's input. key is the user input, value is how many times user gave that number. just `map[input]++`

Comment: Or use the value input by the user (after range check) as the index to the array and increment the element at that index.  There is no need to save the values unless you want to remember the order that the numbers were entered.

Comment: && is the short-cut operator. & will work.

Comment: Ya ingo. I'll give this try kent.

Comment: This problem belongs to the familly of Range Minimum Query.

Comment: @user3033321 does the assignment allows you to use data structures like Map?

Comment: Cheers again NormR that was really helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a frequency array `freq[]`

```
int[] freq= new int[10];// Declare an array of size 10

while (i < 50){
int value = kbin.nextInt();
if (value >= 10 & value <= 19) {
    list[i] = value;

    freq[value-10]++; // Count the number in array position.
    i++;
} else {
    System.out.println("!! Bad number !!");    
   }
}

//Now, display the frequency of number.
for(int k=0;k<freq.length;k++){
  System.out.println("value : " +(k+10)+" frequency : "+freq[k]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have another array with length 10.
In the i'th cell of the array, add the number of times the value i+10 got inserted.
Then just normalize (divide by 50).

Answer (score 0):

```
I worked on this and here is the code,

`import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
public class MapMagic {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Integer,Integer> map=new  HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        Scanner kbin = new Scanner(System.in);
        int list[]=new int[50];
        int i=0;
        System.out.println("Enter limit:");
        int limit = kbin.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Elements");
        while (i < limit) {
            int key = kbin.nextInt();
            if(map.get(key)==null){
                map.put(key,1);
            }
            else{
                int temp=map.get(key);
                temp++;
                map.put(key,temp);
            }
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println("Occurence");
        Set<Entry<Integer, Integer>> var =map.entrySet();
        for (Iterator iterator = var.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            Entry<Integer, Integer> entry = (Entry<Integer, Integer>) iterator.next();
            System.out.println(entry.getKey()+":"+entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
`
```